# How to properly create a CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE script for compiling with mingw on Windows in CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, toolchain

I want to build a very simple project using mingw compiler on Windows which is not in PATH and I don't want to manually set the environment variable before calling CMake command.
Some people suggested using CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to automate this process but I couldn't get it to work.

I have CLion installed on my PC and in the following directory it contains mingw toolchain:

Full path to gcc:

```
E:\Softwares\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\gcc
```

Full path to g++:

```
E:\Softwares\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++
```

You need to set up the proper environment variable before calling CMake. So as people said I created two versions of .cmake toolchain files to address this limitation. (Ninja is used for the generator)

mingw-toolchain.cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "E:/Softwares/CLion/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "E:/Softwares/CLion/bin/mingw/bin/g++.exe")
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

When I run:

```
cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:/Users/Nima/Desktop/CMake/mingw-toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/Nima/Desktop/CMake/Install/x64-release -SC:/Users/Nima/Desktop/CMake -BC:/Users/Nima/Desktop/CMake/Build/x64-release
```

This is the error I get:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Softwares/CLion/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Softwares/CLion/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at E:/Softwares/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
  The C compiler

    "E:/Softwares/CLion/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/Nima/Desktop/CMake/Build/x64-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-86u4p4

    Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~1/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_372a2 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_372a2.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_372a2.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    E:\Softwares\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_372a2.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c C:\Users\Nima\Desktop\CMake\Build\x64-release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-86u4p4\testCCompiler.c
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
         

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Nima/Desktop/CMake/Build/x64-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Nima/Desktop/CMake/Build/x64-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
So how should I change the *toolchain.cmake file?
```

Best regards.

Comment: Why don't you just set the proper environment variables and add gcc to PATH once and for all. It's not like you have to do it every single time.

Comment: Yes but I want it to be automated by CMake than manually add it to PATH.

Comment: Just use MSYS2. The CMake it ships will automatically use its MinGW.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I want to do it using CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE. Does MSYS2 contain a .cmake script so that I can use it with CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE?

Comment: Please, do **not re-ask** the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271282/how-to-set-up-the-simplest-cmake-toolchain-for-mingw-compilers). If your question is not answered... then it means none of the visitors knows the answer. In that case you need to wait. If you want to attract more attention to your question, then you may offer a bounty. (But make sure that the question post is in the best shape that you can afford: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: As for you intention to express every CMake setup using a toolchain, then I don't find it to be a right way. A toolchain is not a cure for everything. E.g., none toolchain can replace proper selection of the [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). You could also look into [presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html), which provide more abilities to pass predefined parameters to `cmake` when configure a project.